# Chef : knife.rb ignores ssl_verify_mode :verify_none when bootstrapping a node

Tags: linux, ssl, chef-infra

I am trying to bootstrap a node from chef workstation. I have everything configured, and also the knife client list returns the name of the validator. However, when I bootstrap a node, I get the following error

> ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: XXX.XXX.XXX - 
>   hostname XXX.XXX.XXX does not match the server certificate

Although I have configured the knife.rb and added the line

```
ssl_verify_mode :verify_none.
```

The chef server and workstation don't have domain names; only IPs.

Is there a way to work around the SSL check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure the `knife.rb` parameter is used for bootstrapping.

There's a `--node-ssl-verify-mode NONE` for the [`knife bootstrap`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#options) command, which will set the `ssl_verify_mode` parameter to `:verify_none` on the node bootstrapped.

But really, configure a DNS system; you'll have another load of problems using IP as nginx won't be able to properly route the requests without a hostname defined.

Comment: You are right, that was the only way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in Tensibai response. It should be  `--node-ssl-verify-mode none` (lowercase)